# VBA IE11 Browser Automation click Log Off button doesnt work

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate the pulling of a report from a client portal.

Figured out how to juggle instances if IE, how to navigate through Iframes. Few other hurdles.

I am down to 1 button that I cannot click without using sendkeys to tab all the way up the page.

The (lightly sanatized) HTML for the element im trying to hit is:

```
<span class="logoff_container" id="logoff">

<span tabindex="0" title="Log off" class="logofflink logofflinkNormal" id="buttonlogoff"  onmouseover="logofflink._handlers.onlogofflinkMouseHover('buttonlogoff');" onmouseout="logofflink._handlers.onlogofflinkOut('buttonlogoff');" onmousedown="logofflink._handlers.onlogofflinkMouseDown('buttonlogoff');" onfocus="logofflink._handlers.onlogofflinkMouseHover('buttonlogoff');" onblur="logofflink._handlers.onlogofflinkOut('buttonlogoff');">

<span class="button_inner">Log off</span></span></span>
```

Using this sendkeys logic, I can successfully make the logoff dialogue box open:

```
    ''Logout
For i = 1 To 32

Application.SendKeys "+{Tab}"
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01") * 0.55)
Next i

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
Application.SendKeys "~"
```

I want to be able to make the logout dialogue box appear with this:

```
IE.document.getElementByID("buttonlogoff").Click
```

As a go between, I have tried this, and it does not work (the element focuses. The class of the element changes. The logout window does not open).:

```
Set LogOffButton = IE.document.getElementById("buttonlogoff")
LogOffButton.Focus
Application.SendKeys "~"
```

I have poked and prodded ad nauseum. I can say with 100% certainty that getElementByID is successfully getting the HTML Span element. I've tried every sequence of .FireEvent prior to the click. I've tried grabbing the HTML table cell element that these elements reside within and clicking that.

I for the life of me cannot figure out why a both right and left clicks with a mouse opens the window, keyboard tabbing and hitting enter opens the window, application.sendkeys and waiting for a minute (almost always) works, but .focus > SendKeys and .click on the element don't open the window.

Any chance for some guidance on how to crack this puzzle?

Comment: Is the button part of a form?

Comment: example if a form may be something like `IE.document.forms(0).Submit` without seeing the full html code, cant be sure, however the code you have here `IE.document.getElementByID("buttonlogoff").Click` looks correct so i assume it must be within a form.. Do a search on the word form when viewing the html elements..

Comment: There are forms on the page, but I do not believe the button is part of any of them. It is in a table, that is in another table, that's in a div. Which confused me because I thought you had to get each table, and then get the element to get to the element, but as I said, I am successfully focusing on the element.

Comment: Maybe my answer.. which is not accepted yet.. but has a ton of code in it... will help you on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59721130/excel-vba-submitting-data-via-ie-on-an-online-ms-forms-not-working/59721369#59721369

Comment: you can use ExecScript to fire the JS.

Comment: I do have a feeling that the issue is some JS hidden somewhere on the page, but I do not know how to find what JS i need to fire. I havent seen any, like, debugger that will tell me the JS that just fired when I click the button.

Answer (score 0):

The button has no click event, it has an onmousedown event. You can try to trigger this with the following line of code (set the right string for *browser.document*):

```
Call TriggerEvent(browser.document, LogOffButton, "onmousedown")
```

And this procedure:

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```