# scraping multiple page web table with vba

Tags: html, excel, vba

i'm trying to save in excel with vba the second page of the table in the url below in code but i'm unable to use the click property, may you help me please? i have searched everywhere on the web without results. thanks.

```vb
Sub BrowseSiteTableObjectX()
    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim Docm As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLAtab As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLArow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim iRow As Long

    With IE
        .navigate "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener"
        Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
           DoEvents
        Loop
    End With

    Set Docm = IE.document

    Docm.getElementsByClassName("symbol-screener__pagination")(0).getElementsByClassName("next")(0).Click

    Set Docm = IE.document

    Set HTMLAtab = Docm.getElementsByClassName("symbol-screener__table")(0)

    For Each HTMLArow In HTMLAtab.getElementsByClassName("symbol-screener__row")
        iRow = iRow + 1
        Cells(iRow, 1) = HTMLArow.getElementsByClassName("symbol-screener__cell symbol-screener__cell--ticker")(0).innerText
        Cells(iRow, 2) = HTMLArow.getElementsByClassName("symbol-screener__cell symbol-screener__cell--company")(0).innerText
        DoEvents
    Next HTMLArow

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set Docm = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: in other words the line "Docm.getElementsByClassName("symbol-screener__pagination")(0).getElementsByClassName("next")(0).Click" don't go to the second page of the table.

Comment: Please remove java and javascript tags.

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps, in this post, I outlined multiple ways to deal with elements on the page. You need to consider what is happening when you 'click' the Next button. It could be submitting a form, running page javascript,

[Excel VBA Submitting data via IE on an online MS Forms not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59721130/excel-vba-submitting-data-via-ie-on-an-online-ms-forms-not-working/59721369#59721369)

See if any of those ideas help. You might find ExecScript is the best, since the Next button probably links back to script on the page to load the next set of data. Just need to watch your Chrome Dev Tools and see what happens.

Good luck!

Comment: Also have a look here, the next li, houses a link element. So you might need to get the Li with elementsbyclassname('next') and then reference another get element ('a') and loop it to get a htmlanchor element and then action that.
<li class="next">
                         <a tabindex="0" role="button"></a>
</li>

Answer (score 1):

Pagination is sometimes a tricky thing but on this page it's easy. I fixed also some other issues. Please read the comments in the code:

```
Sub BrowseSiteTableObjectX()
  Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
  Dim Docm As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
  Dim HTMLAtab As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
  Dim HTMLArow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
  Dim nodePagiantionNext As Object 'I do those things always by late binding
  Dim iRow As Long
  Dim lastPage As Boolean

  With IE
    'Set the following line to 'False' to make IE invisible
    'You can also set IE to full screen, scroll to the page
    'count and watch it advance. I give each page 5 seconds
    'to load. From what I have seen, this is partly necessary
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener"
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
  End With
  'The page loads data after the IE says he's ready. So you need a manual break for a few seconds
  'Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(pause_hours, pause_minutes, pause_seconds))
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5))

  Set Docm = IE.document

  'You need a loop to go through all pages
  '(The IE is a diva. It can be you must start him every loop round. But for the given url it
  'works for 312 pages with the 5 second break)
  Do
    'If you click the 'next' link here, you are on the second page before you read out any data
    'You must do the click after reading data from the first page
    '
    'Give some seconds after the click to load the new page
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5))

    Set Docm = IE.document

    Set HTMLAtab = Docm.getElementsByClassName("symbol-screener__table")(0)

    For Each HTMLArow In HTMLAtab.getElementsByClassName("symbol-screener__row")
      iRow = iRow + 1
      Cells(iRow, 1) = HTMLArow.getElementsByClassName("symbol-screener__cell symbol-screener__cell--ticker")(0).innerText
      Cells(iRow, 2) = HTMLArow.getElementsByClassName("symbol-screener__cell symbol-screener__cell--company")(0).innerText
      'DoEvents 'Why?
    Next HTMLArow

    'You can't click the li tag. You must click the link which is the first child of the li tag
    'But you must also know when the last page is reached. Thats  when the CSS class changes to "next disabled"
    Set nodePagiantionNext = Docm.getElementsByClassName("symbol-screener__pagination")(0).getElementsByClassName("next")(0)
    '
    'Check if the CSS class has been changed to "disabled".
    'Short explanation, because we ask for "next" first, and if this should work,
    '"next" must also match "next disabled". This is true.  "next" is the first
    'part of "next disabled". All CSS class names with the same beginning fit for
    'a node collection to be created
    If nodePagiantionNext.getAttribute("class") = "next disabled" Then
      'If last page end loop
      lastPage = True
    Else
      'If not the last page, click for next page
      nodePagiantionNext.FirstChild.Click
    End If
  Loop Until lastPage

  IE.Quit
  Set IE = Nothing
  Set Docm = Nothing
End Sub
```